# How to send multiple Network requests sequentially using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a list of files in android. User can select multiple files and delete them. For each file a network request should be made and wait for it response before sending the second one. How can I do this using AsyncTask. That is, Send request sequentially on server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API level 11 and above, `AsyncTask` executes `serially`.
Before API level 11, it executes `parallelly` .

If your application is supporting < API 11, then it cannot be done, i.e. you cannot run serially on < API 11 devices. Otherwise , for >API 11 devices, `execute()` will run it serially.